# RSA_generate_key() openssl: exp argument

Tags: c, unix, openssl, rsa

I've found on internet that the exp argument of the function "is typically 3,17, or 65,537".

How I choose it, and what is the difference between using 3,17 and 65,537?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose your exponent so that it is relatively prime to p-1 for all primes p which divide the modulus. Although you may encounter problems with some libraries if you try to use other values than `3,5,17,257,65537` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation) offers more details on the RSA key-generation)

[Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c) is a very good description on a related question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good answer to your question: [Should RSA public exponent be only in {3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537} due to security considerations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c)

And if you love math, you could also browse through this:

[some math](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node41.html)

Answer (score 1):

I advise to stick to what NIST recommends today in [SP 800-56B](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56B/sp800-56B.pdf): the value 65'537 (in truth they recommend any odd positive integer no smaller than that).

The only reasons for choosing lower number (e.g. 3 or 17) are related to:

- compatibility to existing systems that only support specific public exponents
- performance issue when verifying a signature or encrypting a payload.

If those are valid concerns for you, you should consider lower exponents, but you should be aware that you become more sensitive to flaws in the RSA implementation.